# Best way to continually stream out variables as a function is computed?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance

I have a function that I need to make multiple instances of, but that function requires variables from the previous instance to run. There are 5 variables at different stages of the function that the other ones need to run, so I want to be able to create 5 different instances of the function because the function that inputs data into this function is much faster.

What I am in the process of doing is creating a class with a buffer that will notify each other when each stage is computed by using conditional variables and ofcourse mutex to lock.

What is the fastest way to do this to minimize any time lost since the whole goal is to create multiple instances of this function to process data in multi-threaded manner?

Comment: This is far to broad in its current form.  If you included the code you're trying to improve, we might be able to provide some suggestions.

Comment: "Multiple instances of a function"? "Previous instance"? "Stages of a function"? I suspect that your problem is that you don't understand what you are trying to achieve, because you haven't mastered your tools (i.e. C++).